# Upgrading to freebsd10 breaks apache24

Tags: ssl, freebsd, configuration, apache-2.4

Until now I was using freebsd9 with apache22 with ssl, every thing went well. But recently I moved to freebsd10 (fresh install) and then installed apache24 with same config as on old machine.

Everything is ok except that apache24 when used with ssl on port 443 produces error `AH022240: Server should be SSL-aware but has no certificate configured [Hint: SSLCertificatefile] ((null): 0)` And Apache24 refuses to run.

`openssl verify mycertificate` produces error 18 which (I think) is normal as it is a self signed certificate.

I have done whatever I could searching google/yahoo, and trying treatments suggested there but no results.

Alas my bad luck I have just formatted my old hard disk without any backup in order to install freebsd10.

Comment: Check if the mod_ssl module is availiable using `phpinfo()`  Also  `SSLCertificateFile` is the directive which requires a path to the certificate.  A self-signed certificate should return an OK message but will indicate that it's not signed. For more details try http://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/network-apache.html

Comment: "Alas my bad luck I have just formatted my old hard disk without any backup in order to install freebsd10." -> I guess you are not talking about production server, are you?

Comment: @EricDANNIELOU You are right.

Comment: @val0x00ff, I can not check what you suggest as Apache24 is not running. -(

Comment: @Nishan You need to first be able to start apache24 as it is, without ssl or anything. write a  <? phpinfo(); ?>  and see what modules there are. If you cannot start apache then i the problem is your apache not ssl.

Comment: I SOLVED THE PROBLEM -)

THANKS TO MY STARS & THE COMMUNITY

Answer (score 6):

Your problem is not FreeBSD, it's Apache.
Apache 2.4 has ***substantially different configuration file directives*** than Apache 2.2.

You  cannot just throw the 2.2 configuration file in place and start your 2.4 server using it - you will need to put important bits (like the SSL Certificate and Key files - per the error message you're getting) in place, and update your configuration (or write a new configuration file implementing the same functionality as your previous one) so Apache 2.4 understands it..

[Refer to the Apache manual (***which you should have read BEFORE upgrading***) for specific instructions](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html).

Comment: I respect and value your advice. 

But, BUT I am running *Apache24 with same config on FreeBSD91* NO PROBLEMS WITH SSL OR NO SSL AT ALL, my surprise.

*APACHE IS INNOCENT GUY IN THIS CASE* _~)_

I am not blaming but sure FreeBSD10 has changed its way of working potentially, which I have to understand afresh.